# check array of object to checking condition in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

check array of object to checking condition.conditions are
Array of object is initially is empty.

1.if array is empty,when action occurred,add object to array.

2.if array has object check if it is already exists.if found delete the object from array,otherwise add to array.

i tried below code.

```
  var arr = [];
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".rating").click(function() {
            var idx = $(this).closest('td').index();

            var userskill = {
                tech : $(this).closest('td').siblings('td.tech').text(),
                skill : $('#listTable thead th').eq(idx).text(),
                rValue : $(this).val()

            }
            add(userskill);
        });

    });

function add(userskill) {
    var flag = false;
    arr.push(userskill);
    for(var i in arr){
        if((arr[i].tech==userskill.tech)&&(arr[i].skill==userskill.skill)){
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) could be interesting for your problem. E.g. the [isEqual](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) method allows object comparision.

edit:

Code using _.findWhere:

```
function add(userskill) {
  if(!_.findWhere(arr, userskill)) {
      arr.push(userskill);
  }
}
```

Comment: As I understood, you want to add the object 'userskill' to 'arr' if there is no equal object contained allready. Therefor you could use the _findWhere method. It returns false, if there is no equal object found in the list. The code would look like in the edit above.

Comment: the above code is not working.it'l always adding object to array.even if they are equal..